# Adding a script to index.php

Tags: php, joomla

Dear stackflower users,

A few days ago there was a power outage and my mysql database was lost... (I did have a one month old backup)

So I started looking for a program that makes backups of my mysql database automatically.
I found a script that does exactly this, its called phpMyBackupPro

According to the readme I had to add:

```
    require_once("phpMyBackupPro/schedule_backup.php");
```

To a page that gets loaded frequently (for example index.php)

So I tried adding this to my index.php page of joomla and clearing my joomla and browser cache.
However the backup files are not being created when I load the index.php, when I run the script manually they are however.

So I started looking for some addons that could load php files in joomla, but they either didn't work or they where not compatible with joomla 1.7.

is their anyone who knows how to get this script to work, or knows a better way of automatically backing up mysql databases on windows?

Comment: Do you have server access so that you can set up a cron?

Comment: Where do you want to backup? Backuping to the same server serves no purpose.

Comment: Im making the backup to my external hard drive, And its running windows so I don't think I can use cron.

Answer (score 2):

calling this script from the index.php is bad coding practice. God knows what does this script do!

I recommend [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606), I used it with small and large Joomla installations and it works like charm.

What I recommend more is to have periodic full account backup (e.x. cpanel), these backups holds more info (cron jobs, emails, ...) and are easier and faster to restore (if you have sufficient privilege of course).

EDIT: You don't have to have cpanel to make account backups. You can use shell scripts like [this](http://www.devessence.com/2009/04/10/website-and-database-back-up-shell-script/) or [that](http://terra-byte.org/vps/backup-site-shell-script/) and use cron job to activate them.

Comment: Im hosting it on my own server, so I don't have cpanel.

Comment: Akeeba Backup is the way to go - on of the most well-known and trusted extensions in the Joomla-sphere. If you only need to save your Joomla DB than you will be fine with the free edition. If you need to backup other MySQL tables you need to purchase the Professional version of it.

Comment: Akeeba is well worth the price. It is a standard extension in ever site we build.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid trying to what you mentioned and instead use a Joomla specific extension such as this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/15682?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMDoibGF6eWJhY2t1cCI7fQ%3D%3D

I have used this for years and it has saved my ass on multiple occasions so happily recommend it!

Having said that if you're dead set on what you've mentioned simply add it to the BOTTOM of your template file located: templates/your_templates/index.php

Hope this helps,

Andy

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but id like to backup my phpbb database and other joomla database as well.

Also I tried to add require_once("../../phpMyBackupPro/schedule_backup.php"); to the index.php in the template but its just showing it as text at the bottom of the page instead of executing it...

Comment: try <?php require_once("../../phpMyBackupPro/schedule_backup.php"); ?>

Comment: I tried that but it changes my joomla website into a white border...
Also the backup files are still not created

Comment: I'd wager your backup scheduler is timing out or erroring and your PHP errors are disabled. You may be better off using this tutorial to just do the backups through your server (assuming you have SSH access) here: http://www.backuphowto.info/how-backup-mysql-database-automatically-linux-users

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution for windows uswers:

I made a bat file script:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --result-file=E:\mysql\backup.sql "-uroot" "-password" --databases joomla server phpbb
```

This is an example where you replace the text password with your own password and root with the username(in most cases this is root) the database names are joomla, server and phpbb.

This program runs every 1 hour be using the task schedule in windows.